# tax_class_name in product import won't change to none

Tags: magento-2.2.1, tax-class, import-products

I tried to import product by `CSV` file from `backend`. I fill the `tax_class_name` column to `0` but it won't make the product tax to `None` but `Taxable Goods`. And when i check at the database in `tax_class`, there's only `Taxable Goods` and `Retail Customer`.

So, how can i made uploaded product to `none tax class`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insted of writeing 0 into column please write **"None"** . it will work fine becouse magento 2 not accepting numberic value while we importing using CSV.

Comment: please read my question again, `So, how can i made uploaded product to none tax class?` thank you.

Comment: i update my question , if work then please mark question as right